# Calculating very large exponents in python

Tags: python

Currently i am simulating my cryptographic scheme to test it. I have developed the code but i am stuck at one point.

I am trying to take: `g**x` 
where

```
g = 256 bit number
x = 256 bit number
```

Python hangs at this point, i have read alot of forums, threads etcc but only come to the conclusion that python hangs, as its hard for it to process such large numbers.

any idea how can it be done? any two line piece of code, any library, anything that can be done.

Comment: Do you need to take modulus afterwards?

Comment: Cryptography _is_ complex and there is really no reason to shout. Try Googling "Numpy". And if it matters, don't do cryptography yourself.

Answer (score 15):

It's not hanging, it's just processing. It *will* eventually give you the answer, provided it doesn't run out of memory first.

I haven't heard of the result of such a process being used in cryptography though; usually it's the modulus of said power that matters. If it's the same in your case then you can just use the 3-argument form of [`pow()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#pow) instead.

Answer (score 12):

You shouldn't try to calculate x^y directly for huge values of y - as has already been pointed out, this is pretty difficult to do (takes lots of space and processing power). You need to look at algorithms that solve the problem for you with fewer multiplication operations. Take a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring for starters.

Modular exponentiation is also pretty well understood: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation.

You will need to use a python library for large numbers, such as http://gmpy.sourceforge.net/.

If it's any help, I did modular exponentiation in C using [mpir](http://www.mpir.org). I'll attach that code, you'll need to convert it to python of course.

```
int power_modn( mpz_t c, mpz_t b, mpz_t e, mpz_t n)
{
        mpz_t result;
        mpz_t one;
        mpz_t r;

        mpz_t modulus; mpz_t exponent; mpz_t base;

        mpz_init(modulus); mpz_init(exponent); mpz_init(base);
        mpz_init(result); mpz_init(one); mpz_init(r);

        mpz_set_ui(result, 1);
        mpz_set_ui(one, 1);

        mpz_set(base, b);
        mpz_set(exponent, e);  
        mpz_set(modulus, n);

        while ( mpz_cmp_ui(exponent, 0) > 0 )
        {
               if ( mpz_mod_ui( r, exponent, 2) == 1 )
               { 
                        mpz_mul(result, result, base);
                        mpz_mod(result, result, modulus);
               };
               mpz_mul(base, base, base);
               mpz_mod(base, base, modulus);
               mpz_fdiv_q_ui(exponent, exponent, 2);
        }

        mpz_set(c, result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great stuff but python's got it covered with a three argument version of pow()

Comment: Ah ok... I'm not an experienced python developer so I tend to miss bits like that.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not quite sure you appreciate the sheer magnitude of what you're asking Python to do. Raising something to a power `x` where `x` is 256 bits long, is doing the equivalent of 2**256 multiplications, or 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639936 multiplications. As you can imagine, this may take some time. And space, which I guarantee you don't have enough of.

Comment: Well assuming a sane power algorithm, it shouldn't need more than 512 multiplications or so.  But since the result would have on the order of 10**79 bits, space would definitely be a problem!