# Why did my computer slow down and become unresponsive running this python program?

Tags: python

```
x=len(str(2**1000000000))
print(x)
```

I thought it was funny but my computer started to lag and it was unresponsive,what the heck happened?

Comment: It has trouble calculating `2**1000000000`

Comment: Also that would be [a 301,029,996-character string](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=number+of+digits+in+2%5E1000000000). Why did you think this *wouldn't* crash?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/2392235/5320906

Comment: @paisanco, Python's integers can be as huge as possible, limited only by the amount of memory available.

Comment: `x=pow(2,1000000000)` works in a couple of seconds, though converting to a string is still problematic.

Comment: On my machine, it takes more than 7 _seconds_ to even calculate `a = 2**1000000000`. This is a _huge_ number, man. Also, `sys.getsizeof(a) == 133333360`, which is around 133 _megabytes_, which is a lot for a number.

Comment: What exactly happened? Question and title don't match up. Did the program crash? Your computer crashed? Your computer just got slow? Did you get an error message?

Comment: No errors or anything, the computer just got really sluggish and unresponsive, i had to reboot it actually

Comment: Why didn't you just kill the program? Anyway, you're basically asking to do something fairly compute- and memory- intensive. Yes, it can make your computer unhappy but shouldn't crash anything.

Comment: i tried everything but i could not kill it,well i guess i was asking it too much.Whatever

Comment: @pvg if you use Windows it may as well be a crash. Nothing will be useable for hours on end. Even killing the script will become "impossible" once you exceed system memory. LoadingTask Manager, which would allow you to kill it, will often throw an error that it is not possible.

Comment: Well, it isn't 'whatever' - it's totally reasonable to type up random programs just to see what happens and to ask if you don't understand why what happened happened. You should keep doing that. Just make sure to be as precise as possible when describing what you did and and what happened. Take a look at [ask] for next time.

Comment: Will do!Thanks anyways

Answer (score 4):

In Python, usually calculations in the integer world are done with arbitrary size. So it means that if you calculate `2**1000000000`, it will not do this with a 32-bit integer, or a 64-bit integer, but it uses a `long` in Python-2.x, or an `int` in Python-3.x (but an `int` in Python-3.x) has arbitrry size.

`2**1000000000` is however a huge number. It would require 1'000'000'000 bits, or 125'000'000 bytes at least. It also will calculate the power using an algorithm and has to represent the intermediate results as well.

In CPython, it requires 133 MB of memory to store the value. But that is not the end of it. Now you want to convert that to a string. The string will take approximately 301'029'995 digits. Each digits takes at least one byte. So this will take an extra 301 MB of memory, furthermore it will require a lot of work to calculate the decimal representation: each iteration, we have to perform a modulo 10 check, and furthermore we need to devide the number by 10, so it works (at least) quadratic in the number of digits of the number. Since the number of digits is huge (~300 million), it thus requires a huge amount of work.

The `len(..)` operation is not very expensive, but the above steps are expensive in both memory (and somwhat in CPU time, especially the conversion to a string). Memory might seem like a factor we can ignore, but in case we consume huge amounts of memory, the system can slow down, or even freeze. Usually if the system runs out of RAM memory, it will start using *swap* memory: it will swap out parts of RAM memory to the hard disk drive, which is *very* slow (compared to RAM memory).

The above sketched way to obtain the number of digits is definitely not a good one. It will for instance not work with negative numbers as well. There is a mathematical concept called *logarithms*, and if you take the *log<sub>10</sub>* of a number, you get the number of digits *minus* one. There are some extra problems here:

1. the `log10` of negative numbers is *not define*; and
2. nor is the `log10` of zero.

But we can work around these issues. For instance by constructing the function:

```
from math import log10, floor

def number_of_digits(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 1 + floor(log10(abs(x)))
```

This will work for all integer values. In case you want to calculate the number of digits of a power, we can even prevent calculating `2**1000000000` in the first place:

```
from math import log10, floor

def number_of_digits_power(x, y):
    return 1 + floor(y * log10(x))
```

So the number of digits is:

```
>>> number_of_digits_power(2, 1000000000)
301029996
```

This works effective in both speed and memory.

Comment: That pretty much sums it up,thanks for taking the time to answer!Gonna try it.

Comment: Python 2 isn't that different in this regard. Yes, `int` and `long` are separate types, but Python automatically switches to from `int` to `long` as necessary. `2` and `1000000000` are both `int` values, but `2**1000000000` will be a `long`.

Answer (score 2):

You're describing the classic reaction for running out of memory. Your OS starts paging out memory and writing it to hard drive (see [Virtual Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory)). Your computer will get especially slow if your virtual memory is paged to a spinning hard drive. Any program that tries to run after its memory has been paged out will have to read the memory back from disk which is a very slow process. But your main program that keeps eating more memory is still running, so all of your other processes are left fighting over what little memory is left. Even normal file I/O is slowed down because your storage is busy with the virtual memory. This endless paging in and out of memory is why your computer is so slow.

As others have mentioned in the comments, calculating and storing `2**1000000000` by itself doesn't require a lot of CPU or memory. It's your conversion of that integer to a string that is eating all the memory. You can verify this by running:

```
x = 2**1000000000
```

There should be no conversion to a string when you assign it to a variable this way.