# Working with big numbers in Python and writing them to file

Tags: python

I'm trying to find an efficient way to do the following in Python:

```
   a = 12345678901234567890123456**12345678
   f = open('file', 'w')
   f.write(str(a))
   f.close()
```

The calculation of the power takes about 40 minutes while one thread is utilized. Is there a quick and easy way to spread this operation over multiple threads?

As the number is quite huge, I think the string function isn't quite up to the task - it's been going for almost three hours now. I need the number to end up in a text file.
Any ideas on how to better accomplish this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392235/calculating-very-large-exponents-in-python

Comment: Why do you need the exact value of a 2-billion digit integer?

Comment: have you tried using python's `pow`? Traditional exponentiation with numbers this large is not recommended.

Comment: @chepner: nah, it's only 309,771,764 digits. But I bet the calculation takes a *lot* more memory than that.

Comment: Ah, OK, I think I can work out an algorithm that does it a bit quicker. @snnguyen, no I haven't yet tried out the pow function - will do next time.

Comment: Sorry, no time for a detailed answer now. `pow()` won't help in this case. No easy way to parallelize. Your real problem is base conversion:  Python uses a variant of base 2 internally, and converting to base 10 (for a string) takes time _quadratic_ in the number of bits. Very, very slow. Try writing out, e.g., `hex(a)` instead. Much faster. Or use the `decimal` module, which works in a variant of base 10 to begin with.

Comment: `pow` won't help: `OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')`

Comment: @usr2564301 Yeah, I rounded both up to ballpark it with `(10**26)**(10**8)`.

Comment: @TimPeters, interesting, thank you.

Comment: Did you try `numpy.power()` with something like `numpy.ALLOW_THREADS=8` or higher (if your machine can handle it)?

Comment: I'm still curious: What do you need this for?

Comment: @StefanPochmann I'm always looking for ways to reliably reproduce huge chunks of data from easy to remember patterns, mainly for encryption purposes - not that this is particulary secure...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would like to give a lavish ;-) answer, but don't have the time now.  Elaborating on my comment, the `decimal` module is what you really want here.  It's much faster at computing the power, and *very* **very** much faster to convert the result to a decimal string:

```
>>> import decimal
```

You need to change its internals so that it avoids floating point, giving it more than enough internal digits to store the final result.  We want exact integer arithmetic here, not rounded floating-point.  So we fiddle things so `decimal` uses as much precision as it's capable of using, and tell it to raise the "Inexact" exception if it ever loses information to rounding.  Note that you need a 64-bit version of Python for `decimal` to be capable of using enough precision to hold the exact result in your example:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> c = decimal.getcontext()
>>> c.prec = decimal.MAX_PREC
>>> c.Emax = decimal.MAX_EMAX
>>> c.Emin = decimal.MIN_EMIN
>>> c.traps[decimal.Inexact] = 1
```

Now create a `Decimal` for the base:

```
>>> base = decimal.Decimal(12345678901234567890123456)
>>> base
Decimal('12345678901234567890123456')
```

And raise to the power - the exponent will automatically be converted to `Decimal`, because the base is already `Decimal`:

```
>>> x = base ** 12345678
```

That takes less than a minute on my box!  The reasons for that are involved.  It's not really because it's working in base 10, but because the person who wrote the `decimal` module implemented "advanced" algorithms for doing very large multiplications.

Now convert to a string.  Because it's already stored in a variant of base 10, converting to a decimal string goes very fast (a few seconds on my box, just because the string has hundreds of millions of digits):

```
>>> y = str(x)
>>> len(y)
309771765
```

And, for sanity, let's just look at the last 10, and first 10, digits:

```
>>> y[-10:]
'6044706816'
>>> y[:10]
'2759594879'
```

As  @StefanPochmann noted in a comment, the last 10 digits can be obtained very quickly with native ints by using modular (3-argument) `pow()`:

```
>>> pow(int(base), 12345678, 10**10)
6044706816
```

Which matches the last 10 digits of the string above.  For the first 10 digits, we can use `decimal` again but with much less precision, which will cause it (you'll just to have trust me on this) to use a different approach under the covers:

```
>>> c.prec = 12
>>> c.traps[decimal.Inexact] = 0  # don't trap on rounding!
>>> base ** 12345678
Decimal('2.75959487945E+309771764')
```

Rounding that back to 10 digits matches the earlier result, and the exponent is consistent with the length of `y` too.

Comment: I'm quite surprised that already the *power* appears to be much faster with `Decimal` than with `int`. I tried `base**100000` which took 0.74 seconds and `int(base)**100000` which took 4.4 seconds. I guess `int` doesn't use those "advanced" algorithms? Do you know why not?

Comment: Also, I suggest to add `pow(12345678901234567890123456, 12345678, 10**10)` to the sanity check (instantly says 6044706816, confirming what you got).

Comment: @StefanPochmann, CPython's int multiplication does nothing fancier than Karatsuba multiplication.  Parts of the decimal module are far fancier, using number-theoretic transformations (similar in spirit, but not in details, to, e.g., FFT-based multiplication).  That was the author's own idea of fun ;-)

For the core, we tend to resist things like that, advising people who want to live in a giant-int world to use industrial-strength giant int libraries instead (like `gmp`).

Comment: Thanks. At the bottom of https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/decimal.html I also found a bit about that now under the question *"Is the CPython implementation fast for large numbers?"*.

Comment: @TimPeters Thank you very much. It's absolutely amazing how much faster this method is.