# How much RAM do I need to execute x=10**10**10 in Python?

Tags: python, numbers, ram

By timing the execution of `x=10**10**n` for n up to 8, I estimate that about 4.3 days would be needed to execute `x=10**10**10` on my system.  What I need to know, however, is whether I would have enough RAM.  (My 64-bit Windows system has 16GB of RAM, 10.5GB free at the beginning of execution.)

Is it correct that executing `x=10**10**10` requires about `log_2(10**10**10)` bits, i.e. about `33*10**9` bits, or about 4.1 GB of RAM?

Is there some Python or system function that will report the amount of RAM used by `x=10**10**n` for n up to 8, so I could estimate the amount needed for n=10 (similar to what I did for the execution times)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a bit of overhead in the standard Python integer representation; it only uses 30 bits of each 32-bit word. So your memory estimate is a bit low; you would get a better estimate by multiplying by 32.0/30. But you have enough memory if a single Python process is allowed to use that much on your system.

You can get a more precise measure of the size of a primitive object using `sys.getsizeof`, which shows that the estimate can be made pretty close:

```py
>>> import sys.getsizeof
>>> getsizeof(10**10**7)
4429264
>>> log2(10) * 10**7
33219280.94887362
>>> log2(10) * 10**7 * (32/30) / 8
4429237.459849816
```

By the way, for calculations involving numbers this size, you'll find that the `decimal` module is a lot faster. But you have to modify the decimal "context" to allow numbers of arbitrary precision; instructions can be found at the end of the [FAQ in the module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/decimal.html#decimal-faq)

Comment: What exactly is `decimal` faster at? Surely not computing integers of the size of 10\*\*10\*\*10 (unless that is exactly the problem to be solved, i.e. powers of 10).

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk: it's faster at multiplying very big numbers. TIAS

Comment: See, for example, this answer and its comments. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60066592/1566221. There are also informative threads on the Python dev list.

Comment: @Pres: As a specific example, using Python v3.9 on my laptop, it took 13.78 seconds to compute `13**10**7`, and just 1.05 seconds to compute `Decimal(13)**10**7`. (The gap narrowed a bit on Python v3.11, to 10.35s vs. 1.61s. The decimal module seems to have taken a performance hit of about 50% between v3.9 and v3.10, while built-in integers have gotten a bit faster. I don't know what happened.) And the relative performance of decimal improvesç as the exponent grows. An alternative to decimal is to use a low-level GMP interface, but the decimal module is easier to use.

Comment: That's unexpected, thanks for that information.