# How to take the 5th power python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

I want to find the 5th power of a number given by the user. Can i do this without typing:

```
ans = n * n * n * n * n
```

and can it be used for higher powers?

Comment: [`pow()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow)

Comment: what do you mean? didn't work. Think you meant @BKB response

Comment: It is a link to the built-in function `pow()`. Did you read it? Did you try? A simple `pow(n, 5)` will do the job. In the link, you also have description of the `**` operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `**` operator for exponents:

```
print(5**12)
>>> 224832
```

We can use this more generally using variables.

```
exponent = 5
n = 12
ans = n ** exponent
print(ans)
>>> 248832
```

**Other Methods**
Since the `**` operator caps at an exponent of 256, we can use the built-in `pow()` function for larger exponents. However, these numbers can be very large.

```
power = pow(base, exponent)
```

The `math` and `numpy` libraries also can do this using the `math.pow()` and `numpy.power()` functions.

Comment: To answer OP's second question "Can it be used with higher powers," the answer is yes, but there are numerical limitations https://stackoverflow.com/q/2392235

Comment: I know the limitations and that it caps ant 255, but for the number 5 and any realistic uses, this should work as an operator, making it the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the `**` operator is to use the math library functions.

```
import math
math.pow(x, y)
```

Note that this returns a floating point value, while the `**` operator will return an int or float based on the type of x.